# NExpectation with complex condition

Tags: probability-or-statistics, conditional

When I run a computation for NExpectation with a condition of the following form -- T>R>P -- the computation runs fine. But when I add another inequality -- T>R>P>S -- it gives me an 'invalid input' error. It still produces an output. But I have reason to think that the output is incorrect. Why am I getting an error message? Why is Mathematica still returning an output given that I am getting an error message? Can I trust the output?

To further clarify, here are the two inputs.

The first:

```
NExpectation[
 R \[Conditioned] {R > P > T}, {T \[Distributed]                NormalDistribution[],R \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
  P \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
  S \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]
```

The second:

```
NExpectation[
 R \[Conditioned] {R > P > T > S}, {T \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[], R \[Distributed]                   NormalDistribution[],P \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
  S \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]
```

The first input returns: 0.846284.

The second input returns:

NExpectation: Invalid input. 1.02938

Notice that the only difference between the inputs is the extra '>S' in the condition of the second input. Also, the second input produces an output even though it says 'Invalid input'.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please edit the question and include the actual Mathematica code that you are using. Otherwise, it is very difficult to provide any useful answer :)

Comment: Similar problem, but with the formula, not the condition: `NExpectation[(w + x) \[Conditioned] w > 2, 
 Thread[{w, x} \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]]`
vs.
`NExpectation[(w) \[Conditioned] w > 2, 
 Thread[{w, x} \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]]` -- I can inspect the integral used to compute the expectation with `Trace[
 NExpectation[(w + x) \[Conditioned] w > 2, 
  Thread[{w, x} \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]],
 exp_NIntegrate :> ReleaseHold[Inactivate[exp, NIntegrate]]]`. The `NExpectation::input` error seems a bug....

Comment: ...OTOH, this gives no error and is probably the correct syntax: `NExpectation[(w + x) \[Conditioned] w > 2, {w, x} \[Distributed] 
  ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[], NormalDistribution[]]]`. It suggests you might not be using the correct syntax.

Comment: @Goofy, looks like a regression bug, because there is no warning in [v13.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsxxB.png).

Comment: @Domen BTW, if one executes `On[NExpectation]` and then executes my first example, one sees the original syntax rejected and then rewritten as a product distribution. It seems the error message escapes before it's done massaging the input. (Paul, if you try `On[NExpectation]`, you can turn off the trace messages with `Off[NExpectation]`.)

Comment: Just to emphasize the first comment:  A specific example is needed.

Comment: I've reported a simplified example as a regression in v14.0 to WRI.

Answer (score 1):

While there seems to be some issues with adding the additional condition and using `NExpectation`, I'm guessing what you've presented isn't your "real" problem that you're trying to solve.

What you have is $R$ being the maximum of a sample size of 3 (and 4) from a standard normal distribution.  That mean (and the pdf, cdf, and other moments) can be found exactly for those sample sizes:

```
Mean[OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[], 3}, 3]]
(* 3/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) *)
% // N
(* 0.846284 *)
    
Mean[OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[], 4}, 4]]
(* (6 ArcTan[Sqrt[2]])/\[Pi]^(3/2)  *)
% // N
(* 1.02938 *)
```

Those results match what `NExpectation` gives.  In short, there's no need to use `NExpectation` for the examples you give.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
NExpectation[
  R \[Conditioned] R > P > T > S, {T, R, P, S} \[Distributed] 
   ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
    NormalDistribution[0, 1], NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
    NormalDistribution[0, 1]]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {7.77652, 1.02938} *)
```

And this works faster:

```
NExpectation[
  R \[Conditioned] {R > P > T > S}, {R, P, T, S} \[Distributed] 
   ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[], NormalDistribution[], 
    NormalDistribution[], NormalDistribution[]],
  Method -> {"NIntegrate", {Method -> 
      "LocalAdaptive"}}] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {3.71834, 1.02938} *)
```